# Department.find_all_by_hr_id(@hr_id) is not function in spine.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, spine.js

I am created two scaffold in rails3.1 using spine.js.one scaffold is hr and another one is department.In spine:model hr has_many  department ,department belongs_to hr.In deparment spine:controller

```
class Index extends Spine.Controller
  events:
    'click [data-type=edit]':    'edit'
    'click [data-type=destroy]': 'destroy'
    'click [data-type=show]':    'show'
    'click [data-type=hr]':     'hr'

  constructor: ->
    super
    @active (params) ->
      @change(params.id)

  change: (id) ->
    @item = Hr.find(id)
    @hr_id=@item.id
    @render()

  render: =>
   department = Department.find_all_by_hr_id(@hr_id)
   @html @view('departments/index')(departments: deparment)
```

i tried to list deparment using hr_id in department index page.but i can't using above code.
i have error like this  `Department.find_all_by_hr_id(@hr_id) is not function` in firebug.
Any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing spine.js models with rails models. They are two seperate things. Spine Models do not handle things like they do in rails. Instead you have to call `Department.findAllByAttribute("hr_id", @hr_id)`

You can find an introduction into spine models on this page: [Spine Models](http://spinejs.com/docs/models)

The API documentation can be found here: [Spine Models API](http://spinejs.com/api/models)